# How to know when an app is killed after being in recents for a long time?

Tags: java, android, activity-lifecycle

Which function is called when an app is killed by keeping it in recent apps list for a long time?

I am not asking about when an app is killed by swiping app from the recents list.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such function in Android.

When user closes the app, the process is terminated with no notice. Even `Activity`'s `onDestroy` method is not guaranteed to be called. Only when you explicitly call `finish()`.

If you use `ViewModel` that is tied to the starting Activity's lifecycle, you can try to use `onCleared()` method, which is called always when `ViewModel` is no longer used and will be destroyed. See: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Answer (score 1):

There is no such function.

At the point when the system decides to kill your process, it will do so immediately without calling any more of your code beforehand.

Another answer suggests using ViewModel, but this won't work if you actually need a reliable signal.  It is not guaranteed to trigger, and it may trigger in other circumstances (such as the user backing out of the activity, but the app process not being killed).